# Performance of spatio_temporal_voxel_layer with LaserScan data

Tags: navigation, ros2, ros-humble, nav2

Today, I use the out of the box "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer" plugin with a LaserScan message coming from my stereo camera (and so I convert depth image to LaserScan).

Unfortunately, I'm not happy with that because it doesn't contain the "temporal" feature.

That's why I want to move to the "spatio_temporal_voxel_layer" plugin.
Before that, I'm a bit worried about the performances of this plugin mainly because it converts LaserScan to PointCloud ("Voxel") so from 2D I'm back to 3D objects.

Is this library ables to efficiently deal with LaserScan data ? If not, is there an alternative to have temporality ?
In other words, how to detect obstacles in the FOV of the camera while forgetting those not in this FOV in an efficient manner ?

Comment: Why not just try it and see if its a problem for you? It should be a simple configuration file change and you can measure the performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't be that easy because I'm running on Ubuntu 22 and it seems there is an issue related to OpenVDB. That's why I would like to have an answer before if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to this plugin and didn't see any regression in term of performance ! So it looks like it deals with LaserScan the right way !